# How to properly constrain an iterator based function using concepts

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20

I have trouble understanding the concepts defined in the <iterator> header. I couldn't find good examples using them.

I tried to use the concepts in a simple function to provide better error messages. I don't understand why the output_iterator takes a type but input_iterator doesn't any. Furthermore I don't know how to make the `random_assign_working` function more generic.

```cpp
template<typename T, std::input_iterator InputIter, std::output_iterator<T> OutputIter>
requires std::random_access_iterator<InputIter>
auto random_assign(InputIter inputBegin, InputIter inputEnd, OutputIter outBegin) {
  auto inputSize = std::distance(inputBegin, inputEnd);
  for (size_t it = 0; it < inputSize; it++) {
    auto randomIndex = rand()%inputSize;
    auto selectedInput = inputBegin[randomIndex]; // read input
    *outBegin = selectedInput; // write output
    outBegin++;
  }
}

template<std::input_iterator InputIter, std::output_iterator<uint32_t> OutputIter>
requires std::random_access_iterator<InputIter>
auto random_assign_working(InputIter inputBegin, InputIter inputEnd, OutputIter outBegin) {
  auto inputSize = std::distance(inputBegin, inputEnd);
  for (size_t it = 0; it < inputSize; it++) {
    auto randomIndex = rand()%inputSize;
    auto selectedInput = inputBegin[randomIndex]; // read input
    *outBegin = selectedInput; // write output
    outBegin++;
  }
}

int main() {
  {
    std::array<uint32_t, 9> input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    std::forward_list<uint32_t> output;
    random_assign(input.begin(), input.end(), std::front_insert_iterator(output)); // how can I make this work
    random_assign_working(input.begin(), input.end(), std::front_insert_iterator(output)); // working

    std::stringstream buf {};
    buf << "Out ";
    for (auto item : output)
      buf << " " << item;
    std::cout << buf.str() << std::endl;
  }
  {
    std::array<std::string, 9> input = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
    std::vector<std::string> output;
    output.reserve(input.size());
    random_assign(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin()); // how can I make this work
    random_assign_working(input.begin(), input.end(), std::front_insert_iterator(output)); // how can I make this work
  }
}
```

So my questions are:
How to make use of the concepts defined in <iterator> when writing functions.
How do the iterator_tags tie into this?
How do I check for iterator_tags?

I would appreciate learning resources and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand why the `output_iterator` takes a type but `input_iterator` doesn't any.

Because input iterators have concrete type: it's the type you get from `*it`. That's the iterator's reference type (`iter_reference_t<I>`).

But output iterators don't - they just have a set of types that you can write into them. It doesn't matter what `*out` gives you, it matters what types you can put into `*out = x;` You can't ask for something broad like... give me all possible types you can write into my prospective output iterator type, `O`. But you can ask `O` if it accepts a *specific* type `T`.

For instance, `int*` is an input iterator whose reference type is `int&`. But `int*` can also be used a an output iterator - but for a wide variety of types. `int` of course, but also `int16_t`, or `uint64_t`, or `char`, or any other type convertible to `int`.

Hence, you can ask if `I` is an `input_iterator`, but you can only ask if `O` is an `output_iterator` for some type you're writing into it `T`.

---

Let's go through your `random_assign`:

```cpp
template<typename T, std::input_iterator InputIter, std::output_iterator<T> OutputIter>
    requires std::random_access_iterator<InputIter>
auto random_assign(InputIter inputBegin, InputIter inputEnd, OutputIter outBegin);
```

First up, `random_access_iterator` refines `input_iterator`, so you don't need to write both. Just pick the most specific constraint. Once you do that, the type you're writing into `outBegin` is your input iterator's refernece type, so that's the constraint you need:

```cpp
template <std::random_access_iterator I, std::output_iterator<std::iter_reference_t<I>> O>
void random_assign(I first, I last, O out);
```

Next, you want to return useful information. In this case, we're advancing `out` a bunch of times, so we should return its new value.

Full thing:

```cpp
template <std::random_access_iterator I, std::output_iterator<std::iter_reference_t<I>> O>
auto random_assign(I first, I last, O out) -> O {
    // you can use distance, but we know it's random access
    size_t const dist = last - first;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != dist; ++i) {
        // output_iterator requires this work
        *out++ = first[rand() % dist];
    }

    // law of useful return
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate the other small improvements you made to my code! Can you add a small section explaining what the iterator tags mean? Currently I think they only matter when I create my own iterator correct? Do know any good resources for learning more about iterators? Cpp reference wasn't very helpful. <iterator> doesn't have many examples.